# Getter method for final field name

Tags: java, naming-conventions

It may seem a trivial question, but I've searched a lot and couldn't find an answer.
If I have a final field like this:

```
private final double DEGREES;
```

The variabile is written in caps because it's final, but shall also the getter method be in caps? So it would be getDEGREES or getDegress?

Comment: If your aim is to follow convention, then the variable itself should not be in all-caps.

Comment: @eric this is what I thought at first, it doesn't matter but if I want to strictly respect the convention it does.

Comment: Like Nefron said, you shoudlnt provide a getter for final fields... that just makes no sense. so much about convetions. Uppercase constants is good practice and if youd like to access them out of its holding classes scope you should declare the variable as public / protected .

Comment: If it was a private static final variable (Constant) then uppercase is a convention for the name, in that case it may need to have a getter method. The question would be if in that case the getter should use all-caps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be `getDegrees`. And, in my opinion, the only fields that should be in all caps are some `static final` ones. Member fields that are final do not need to be in all caps.

/edit
Indeed, Oracle's [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) say to only to have `static final` constants in all caps, all member variables should be in lowerCamelCase.

Comment: However it doesn't talk about final fields here.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri What do you mean?

Comment: And if you have a `getter` method for a `static final` constant, then should it be in all caps (eg: `getSOME_CONSTANT()`)?

Answer (score 3):

If that is a constant, you can expose it without a getter, as a static field. That seems to be the standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

Proper naming convention for getters, would be getDegrees

Comment: wasnt there when i typed it :(

Comment: still not a good post and wrong in that context that you shouldnt declare getters for final fields